# Is there any way to specify that multiple versions of a dependency are valid for my library?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am using a library that breaks depending on which other crates  I am using. The way around is to downgrade a few dependencies and keep a local version of the library.

It works if I put `MyLibraryDep = {version = "*"}` in my `Cargo.toml`. Since Cargo will then fix dependencies automatically, but crates.io doesn't allow for that.

**Example:**

- If using `MyLibrary`, and `LibraryA` I have to use `MyLibraryDep v0.1.0` in `MyLibrary`
- If using `MyLibrary`, and `LibraryB` I have to use `MyLibraryDep v0.2.0` in `MyLibrary`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As specified in the Cargo book, you can use [inequality requirements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#inequality-requirements) and multiple requirements combined to form a range of valid versions.

```
MyLibraryDep = {version = ">=0.1.0, <=0.2.0"}
```

Such a requirement will also allow Cargo to choose the appropriate version and should be allowed by crates.io.